# simple Recurrent Neural Net from scratch using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I've build a simple recurrent neural net with one hidden layer with 4 nodes in it. This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# hyper parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
number_of_epochs = 10000

# Computation Graph

W1 = tf.Variable([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], dtype=tf.float32, name = 'W1')
W2 = tf.Variable([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=tf.float32, name = 'W2')
WR = tf.Variable([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], dtype=tf.float32, name = 'WR')
# b = tf.Variable([[0], [0], [0], [0]], dtype=tf.float32)
prev_val = [[0.0]]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None], name = 'X')
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name = 'labels')

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

z = tf.matmul(X, W1) + tf.matmul(prev_val, WR)# - b 
prev_val = z

predict = tf.matmul(z, W2)

error = tf.reduce_mean((labels - predict)**2)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)

time_series = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
lbsx = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

for i in range(number_of_epochs):
    for j in range(len(time_series)):
        curr_X = time_series[j]
        lbs = lbsx[j]

        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: [[curr_X]], labels: [[lbs]]})

print(sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: [[0]]}))
print(sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: [[1]]}))
```

I'm getting output:

```py
[[ 0.]]
[[  3.12420416e-05]]
```

With input 1, it should output 0 and vice versa. I'm also confused regarding the 'previous value'. Should it be a placeholder? I'd really appreciate your efforts to fix the code.

Comment: I think `prev_val` should be initialized as `prev_val = tf.Variable([[0.0]], trainable=False)` to make sure that it is on your graph.

Comment: And for that matter, you may have better luck initializing your weights from a random distribution. Something like `W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1, 4]))` where you set `shape` to whatever shape you want your weight tensor to take.

Comment: I've tried a few things: just training and running a feed-forward version of your network (surprised this didn't work as it is basically a `not` gate), encoding the labels as one-hot and using `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as the cost, using different optimizers (I like `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`). I am not sure, but I think you may have more luck predicting a meaningful time series than this switching series. The network seems OK, but I can't get it to work either. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, have a look at the nested loops I created to train. Is backpropagation through time done correctly? Maybe the model is correct but training isn't?